# Application works with fiddler ON and doesn't works without fiddler?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, fiddler, silverlight-5.0

I have a silverlight application it makes HTTPS request, it works fine when I am tracing the application with fiddler ON, But it throws Remote server not found error when I don't have fiddler running

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to configure the application *not* to use a proxy?

Comment: Can you add details about the url of your remote server along with your IE connection settings?  Remember that fiddler inserts itself a s a proxy server so if it's not working without fiddler, you're likely looking at a proxy config issues.

Comment: When you are using Https with Fiddler you would get it working and once fiddler is closed it doesnt coz the traffic is intercepted by the Fiddlers test certificates that would have been installed to your cert store. Just deleting them from the store should get you working without fiddler running

Comment: Slightly off topic.. I had the same problem with a WinRT app. I solved it by adding the "Private Networks (Client & Server)" capability to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this recently, in Fiddler Options->HTTPS I had 'ignore server certificate errors' checked. Unchecked that and Fiddler displayed a certificate error.

Ended up adding the code mentioned here 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/43a933b8-e2b1-40a7-ac23-9bf3fc14b1f0

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and found that .NET apps had a global proxy override added in their machine.config.

In our case it was the machine.config in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config folder.

```
<!-- The following section is to force use of Fiddler for all applications, including those running in service accounts -->
    <!-- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config -->

<defaultProxy
    enabled = "true"
    useDefaultCredentials = "true">
    <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```